# Ill-conditionness of a random generated matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

I notice an interesting phenomenon when I try to generate a random s.p.d. matrix. One way to generate an s.p.d. matrix is to first generate an arbitrary matrix $M$, and take $$A=MM^T$$
$A$ is guaranteed to be s.p.d. (maybe semi p.d., in the worst case).

When $M$ is a full random matrix, (say generated by the MATLAB command 'rand(n)+1'),A is usually not so ill-conditioned. But if I force $M$ to be a lower triangular matrix (say using the command 'tril(rand(n)+1)'), which can be seen as a Cholesky factor, $A$ turns out to be far more ill-conditioned.

To illustrate the case, I generate 50 $A$s with full $M$ and another 50 $A$s with lower triangular $M$, and plot the condition number as
[image: condition number]

I cannot explain why. Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Note that $\kappa(MM^T) = \kappa(M)^2$. It is equivalent to say that randomly generated lower-triangular matrices are themselves ill-conditioned.

Comment: Intuitively, we should expect the eigenvalues of the triangular matrix to vary much more wildly, since they depend only on the diagonal entries.

Comment: Random dense matrices are usually well conditioned but condition numbers of random triangular matrices tend to grow exponentially with the dimension. [This article](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~divakar/papers/ViswanathTrefethen1998.pdf) might help you to explain your observation. Note that the ill-conditioning is NOT due to small entries on the diagonal as suggested below.

Answer (score 3):

As I state in my comment, it suffices to show that $M$ is generally ill-conditioned when we force it to be lower-triangular.

Suppose that $M$ is lower-triangular.  Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis vectors. Note that $M e_i$ is the $i$th column of $M$.  The first column $Me_1$ has $n$ random non-zero entries, whereas the last column $Me_n$ has $1$ random non-zero entry.  Note that
$$
\kappa(M) = \max_{\|x\| = \|y\| = 1} \frac{\|Mx\|}{\|My\|} \geq \frac{\|Me_1\|}{\|Me_n\|}
$$
if the random entries have average absolute value $\mu>0$, then we should expect $\|Me_n\|$ to average at $\mu$, whereas $\|Me_1\|$ averages at $\sqrt{n}\,\mu$, so that $\frac{\|Me_1\|}{\|Me_n\|}$ should average at $\sqrt{n}$ (or at least, the the log of the fraction should average at $\log(\sqrt{n})$).

In this way, we see that the shape of the matrix leads to a higher expected condition number.

Comment: By definition, $\kappa(M)=\Vert M \Vert \Vert M^{-1} \Vert$. How does the first equality follow ? Is it  necessary to force $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert y \Vert =1$?

Comment: @ZihinLai It is necessary, actually.  Note that
$$
\|M\| = \max \|Mx\|, \quad \|M^{-1}\| = \max \frac{1}{\|Mx\|}
$$

Comment: The problem is that the condition number and ratio of the extreme eigenvalues (in magnitude) of a  (not only) triangular matrix can be completely different. You can construct a triangular matrix with unit diagonal and an arbitrarily large condition number. The source of ill-conditioning of the random triangular matrices is not on the diagonal.

Comment: But $$\Vert M \Vert \Vert M^{-1} \Vert = \max \Vert Mx \Vert \max \frac {1} {\Vert Mx \Vert} \ge max_{\Vert x \Vert=\Vert y \Vert=1} \frac {\Vert Mx \Vert} {\Vert My \Vert}$$  ?

Comment: Well, we're maximizing the two $x$'s separately